# CakePHP ignore blank fields when trying to update the model

Tags: php, mysql, database, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a registration form with some fields which are not required. The user fills all the fields and then saves. The data is saved normally.

However, if I update data and leave some fields blank, it would update the database record with empty values but CakePHP 1.3 does not update it in the database.

Comment: Post your model, controller action and view if you want we help you

Comment: Please give us something.. To review what you have.

Comment: The question is so vague. Please update the question so that it will be a little more clear.

Answer (score 0):

put a check for empty string and delete the empty keys from the array before saving to database